# Mixed currency products in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, currency, product

I'm evaluating if Magento will be suited to a particular client. They have an unusual requirement where their products may have two price components, one in AUD and one in reward points. There are three combinations of prices: all AUD, all reward points and a fixed mix of both.

I was wondering if Magento supports such a scenario? That is, can it have products flowing through to the shopping cart which have multiple currencies?

My research indicates you can have different currency prices per store for a product in Magento, but you can only have a single price per product within the same store. Also, that the shopping cart only supports a single currency (though you can switch between currencies), so I'm guessing I couldn't add two products, one from each store to the same cart. Are these true?

If my research is correct, I may need to resort to some sort of custom field against the products. If I do that, am I going to have to toss the standard Magento shopping cart out and roll my own?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this might simpler than you think. If you want reward points as currency you can use:

SweetTooth Reward points http://www.sweettoothrewards.com/learn/

It already does what you need, and I have used it in the past several times. The company is very professional and the extension is A++

Comment: @Allen - Thanks for the link, that product certainly looks comprehensive! I'll contact them with some more specific Q's. FYI, my point system will never issue customers with points, they can only redeem them (points come from an external system). Not sure if that affects your recommendation.

Comment: Only in the sense that you need to add some way of loading the points into magento but the system itself should work for what you need. Also if you find my answer useful an upvote is highly appreciated.

Comment: FIY: we're going live with this website in a few days, although we haven't implemented the split currency requirement as yet. I contacted SweetTooth and there were very helpful, we just expended the budget before we got to the this particular requirement. We'll probably use SweetTooth when we get approval for the next stage.

Comment: Glad to hear that and I hope your go live goes down smoothly.