# Magento custom browse catalogue workflow

Tags: magento, catalog

I'm evaluating Magento for a particular client of mine. They want to enforce a particular workflow for browsing the catalogue. They're a travel company which puts together custom holiday packages and want to make sure users enter things like the number of adults / children before selecting accommodation (as number of people will affect available accommodation and pricing).

Note that accommodation is just an example, there are several other different components to a holiday package. And they've given me a 7 step (mostly) linear workflow they want users to follow before we get to anything which might resemble a checkout process (and even then their concept of "checkout" is quite different to Magento's).

I'm thinking of storing accommodation (and each of the other package components) in separate product categories. Then I can restrict what users can see as they browse the catalogue based on what they've already added to their shopping cart.

My research indicates that Magento doesn't really do this kind of thing out of the box. Am I mistaken? Are there add-ons which would support this kind of thing?

If I was to go down this road, would I be redesigning (or indeed, replacing) a large chunk of Magento's catalogue browsing functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up going with Magento as a product base and extending it using some custom code (been a while since I've developed in a LAMP environment!)

I created a static block which is used as the root of the workflow. There are 8 steps in the workflow which get listed in an ordered list. Each item has two custom Magento widgets next to it, which are a) a little tick image displayed when you've completed the workflow stage and b) a link which displays when you're up to that stage, clicking the link takes you to an appropriate catalog page (eg: choose accommodation, hire car, confirm shopping cart, etc).

[image: Magento Workflow Example]

I disabled the normal top catalog navigation to encourage users to keep within the workflow. That is, the mouse over to see more catalog detail of the "holiday planner" is disabled (although you can just navigate to the correct urls if you know them, or are smart enough to use the SEO link at the bottom of the page!).

Everything in your holiday is added as cart products (which has the positive side effect of Magento will remember your holiday if you get part way through it).

There is a big state machine in a helper class to determine what stage of the workflow you're up to. This checks your cart to see if products with particular sku's or from a particular attribute set are added.

I also overrode many URLs and redirects (eg: after you add a product) to send the user back to the root holiday planner page. This added to the workflow as almost every action you did or product you add bounces you back to that workflow page (which always tells you what the next step is).

Answer (score 1):

Well there are several approaches that you can take to implement something like this; but all require that you do custom development work.

You could define your packages as simple products with attributes for each of the specific package options and use that to filter each package from the others, now you would need to create a new module that adds a route on the frontend that is going to be your multistep form that will get all the information once you have all the information you can get a collection of all the products(packages) that match those attributes.

Now the deal there is if that price changes depending on the options selected if that's the case then you might need configurable products or something custom to change the price of each package.

It's really hard to say without real specifications of what your client needs, but if the question is if it's possible with Magento then the answer is yes it all depends on your level of skill :)

Kind Regards

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I was thinking prices changes could be done based on adding multiple products to the cart, eg: 2 x adult, 1 x child. I'm mostly an ASP.NET developer, but I was recommended Magento for this project, so just checking my options. Do you have any comments regarding this (probably much harder) issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787596/mixed-currency-products-in-magento

Comment: Well maybe you can use a bundle or a configurable product to set that up and set it up programatically, or you can always create a product on the fly that matches the exact customer specifications. Magento is very flexible and has a lot of power under the hood.

Comment: Magento's flexibility's not in question! It's my ability to pick it up in a hurry! And, in this case, my client has various requirements which are, shall we say, edge cases. And I don't want to get bogged down in custom work for an unfamiliar product.

Comment: Lol, Sorry what I was trying to say is that from a technical point of view magento is more than capable of doing what you want. But you should also consider the learning curve, timeline and budget of your project. Also if you find my answer useful an upvote is more than welcome :P

Comment: All my research about Magento indicates its capable. That's what scares me a bit! I'm trying to figure out if the timeline, budget, etc allows me to use Magento; I'm sitting on the fence at the moment. You might also be able to recommend something for yet another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789374/magento-geographical-search-and-product-recommendation