# Magento geographical search and product recommendation

Tags: search, magento, geospatial, spatial, product

I'm evaluating Magento for a travel company who will need to do product searches and recommendations based on geographical distance. The company is creating custom holiday packages based on various components (eg: accommodation, tours, restaurant vouchers, etc). These components potentially have overlapping locations (ie: a particular tour might be close enough to several hotels to be considered related to each of them).

As a user builds up their custom package by adding stays at various hotels, I'd like related product recommendations to appear based on geographical location. And, if they search for tours, I'd like closer tours to be weighted toward the top of the catalogue search results.

Nice to have: the ability for the user to select how close / far they consider "close enough" to be (eg: 10km, 50km, 200km, etc).

My research indicates there isn't out of the box support for any sort of spatial queries in Magento. The best solution I could come up with was custom product attributes which list "location" where each product is manually assigned to various locations. But I think that's going to get pretty hard to manage for more than ~50 locations. Is my research correct? Is there an add-on / extension which will fulfil this scenario? Do you think overlapping 50 locations will be manageable in the backend?

Coming from a Microsoft background, my natural inclination would be to enable SQL Server 2008+ spacial functionality and do the queries in the database. Obviously, this option isn't available in the LAMP stack. Am I wrong? Does MySQL support spatial queries like `WHERE productA.Location.GetDistanceFrom(productB.Location) < 50km`?

Answer (score 3):

Mysql supports spatial queries as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/spatial-extensions.html but nothing will help you or free you from entering the relations between products and it's location and you have to implement it yourself as well as extend the search based on location

Comment: Thanks. Good to know MySQL supports spacial stuff (been living in the Microsoft world for too long!). That at least opens some opportunities.